# Exporting PNG sequence as lottie json

Tags: png, adobe, photoshop, lottie, bodymovin

I am a beginner in Adobe After Effects and creating Lottie json files. 
Is there any way to convert PNG sequence to Lottie JSON.

I have tried to export json using After Affects and Bodymovin Plugin.

Comment: What happens when you do try the export?